CASL, checking whether a user can create a new object
I have an organisation (org) and an organisation invite (orginvite) which I want to check the user's ability to create.
  ability.can('create', orginvite);

This check covers whether the user can create an orginvite, but it does not check if they can create an invite for that organisation.
I could use:
  ability.can('create', subject(orginvite', {orgId:idToCheckAgainst});

and inside the permission I could use:
  can(PermissionAction.create, PermissionSubject.orginvite, {
    orgId: usersOrgId,
  });

Is this the right strategy? Or am I better of getting the org the user belongs to, and checking something like:
  ability.can('createorginvite', subject(org', {id:idToCheckAgainst});


Both options are valid. The path to choose depends on how you model the domain in software. Using CRUD is more REST-ish but using custom actions like invite (can invite to org) is more domain driven

But also take into consideration my answer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79218511/check-casl-ability-before-loading-an-entity/79219460#79219460
